# AWS ECS container logs design pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a classic scala app, it produces three different logs in the location

```
/var/log/myapp/log1/mylog.log
/var/log/myapp/log2/another.log
/var/log/myapp/log3/anotherone.log
```

I containerized the app and working fine, I can get those logs by docker volume mount.

Now the app/container will be deployed in AWS ECS with auto scaling group. in this case multiple container may run on one single ecs host.

I would like to use cloud watch to monitor my application logs.

One solution could be put aws log agent inside my application container.

Is there any better way to get those application logs from container to cloudwatch log.

help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

When using docker, the recommended approach is to not log to files, but to send logs to `stdout` and `stderr`. Doing so prevents the logs from being written to the container's filesystem, and (depending on the logging driver in use), allows you to view the logs using the `docker logs` / `docker container logs` subcommand.

Many applications have a configuration option to log to `stdout`/`stderr`, but if that's not an option, you can create a symlink to redirect output; for example, the official NGINX image on Docker Hub [uses this approach](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/c769ad8ab21dfb374fa33d8fb9d0822d0fa8d2e5/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile#L132-L134).

Docker supports logging drivers, which allow you to send logging to (among others) AWS cloud watch. After you modified your image to make it log to `stdout`/`stderr`, your can configure the AWS logging driver.

More information about logging in Docker can be found in the ["logging" section in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/)

Comment: Thanks @thaJeztah. But our app is legacy app and it was not written as a docker way. If we write new app we can follow the docker way. Now we have to deal with legacy apps, so what would be the best way for my use case ?

Comment: @KnowNothing: Does this app use any logging framework? If so, then you can probably override the current behaviour with a custom config file and/or some system properties. Other option would be to use the linking approach suggested by @thaJeztah or you could try running the CloudWatch agent either directly in the container (e.g using a supervisor process) or as a linked container with rsyslog in between (both variants are pretty complex - I'd strongly consider linking to `stdout` or framework reconfiguration, if possible).

Comment: @KnowNothing if you symlink those files to `stdout`/`stderr` it should work; have you tried doing this?

Comment: @thaJeztah linking will work but it will combine all three log files in one logstream, but we want three log files in three different stream in cloudwatch under one log group

Comment: Can we not just install log agent in the ecs host and do the volume mount. I am not sure what will happen if multiple container instance run in the same ecs host with same volume mount ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need log agent if you can change the code.

You can directly publish Custom Metric Data into ColudWatch like this page said: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-publish-custom-metrics.html